# Why does one "Plead Guilty" rather than "Found Guilty" or "Proven Guilty"?

Tags: legalese

I am not sure if this is a Language Question or Legal Question, but in instances of news on court case it is always reported that a "Defendant Pleaded Guilty" but this does not clarify if the defendant admitted to guilt by himself or was proven guilty by evidence presented against him. From my understanding may be there are some legal or lingual technicalities that make the reporting so. Can someone explain why it is always that a Defendant pleads guilty rather than proven to be guilty or found to be guilty?

Comment: Your question is based on a number of basic errors. (1) It is **not** `always reported that a "Defendant Pleaded Guilty"` - defendants frequently plead "not guilty". (2) If the defendant pleads guilty, there is obviously no need for the prosecutor to prove their guilt. This is neither a "language" question nor a "legal" question, it's simply a case of requiring some basic research and comprehension. For more guidance, see [ask] and take our [Tour]. :-)

Comment: I have been to a court case where the defendant didnt admit guilt directly but by his actions and words got into a examination trap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A plea ("guilty"/"not guilty") is entered by the defendant *before* a trial while the verdict ("found guilty"/"proven guilty") is the result *after* a trial.

So, if a defendant "pleaded guilty", they have admitted their guilt prior to the trial. Such an admission would remove the need to conduct the remainder of the trial and, therefore, a verdict of "proven guilty" would not be reached. There are circumstances where a plea can be changed during a trial (from "not guilty" to "guilty") which would effectively stop the trial process.

To sum up, if a "defendant pleaded guilty", it is always the case that they admitted to guilt themselves.

Comment: Possibly worth noting that in the UK, 'pled' (instead of 'pleaded') is not used in England and Wales legal circles, but is normal in Scotland, and also a number of US style guides advise against it, especially in a legal context.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that a guilty plea does not 'remove the need to conduct the remainder of the trial'. An accused person would not be sentenced on their own admission of guilt alone; the facts of the case still have to be established.

Comment: It has been known for innocent people to plead guilty before a trial, perhaps during interrogation, or perhaps due to insanity.

Comment: @KateBunting - Judges' [sentencing remarks](https://www.judiciary.uk/judgment-jurisdiction/crime/) for major UK trials are published; some make harrowing reading. If a defendant pleads guilty at or before the first hearing, there is no 'trial'. Sentencing can happen immediately or later (a 'sentencing hearing'). Before sentencing, the judge must consider all relevant facts (sentence starting point, aggravating & mitigating factors, whether there has been an early guilty plea for which a sentence discount is applicable, mental health of accused, etc). In a complex case that can take some time.

Comment: Time spent in custody is taken off the sentence.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey : Time in custody counts as part of the time to which a person was sentenced, but I'm not sure that's the same as "Time spent in custody is take off the sentence." If a person who has been in custory for six months is sentenced to twelve months, the sentence is still twelve months, not six, but the six months in custody are part of the twelve months.

Comment: @MichaelHardy - yes that's what I meant. Time spent in custody on remand is subtracted from the time to serve following sentence. The sentence remains on the person's record at the length pronounced at sentencing.